# numpy - print documentation for the specific numpy functions, stored in the separate array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, documentation

I have a question - how can I print at one shot the documentation for the numpy functions, stored in an array? To be more clear :

1. I've created an array of all numpy functions:

   `np_docs = np.array(dir(np))`
2. Now, I want to print documentation for functions from 70 to 75 of the array - I do this:

   ```
    for np_doc in np_docs[70:75]:
        print(np.np_doc.__doc__)
   ```
3. I've got an error:

   ```
    "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))
   ```

   `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'np_doc'`

The error make sence, but I still don't understand how to print the documentation for the functions in the array. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `np_docs` contains function names as strings. So you need to access functions from their string names. You can do that with [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) :

```
np_docs = np.array(dir(np))

for np_doc in np_docs[70:75]:
    print(getattr(np, np_doc).__doc__)
```

Comment: Muslimbek Abduganiev, great, thank you for the help!